# How to prove $\lceil\log_{y}{\lceil{x}\rceil}\rceil=\lceil\log_{y}{x}\rceil$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you prove $\lceil\log_{y}{\lceil{x}\rceil}\rceil=\lceil\log_{y}{x}\rceil$ where x maybe any real number but y is a positive integer?

Comment: This is obviously wrong, assuming $\lceil{x}\rceil$ is the largest integer $\ge x$.
$\lceil{\log_2\lceil{0.1}\rceil}\rceil=\lceil{\log_2 1}\rceil = 0, \quad$
but $\lceil{\log_2 0.1}\rceil=\lceil-3.3219\dots\rceil = -3$ (Editid to make $y$ an integer).

Comment: Of course, I mean the **smallest** integer $\ge x$, but unfortunately the edit time window is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement only makes sense when $y>1$ and $x>0$.

When $0<x\leq{1\over y}$ the statement is **wrong**: The left side is $=0$ and the right side $\leq-1$.

When ${1\over y}<x\leq1$ then both sides are $=0$. So from now on we assume $x>1$.

Let $y>1$ and $t>1$ be real, and let $n$ be integer. Then
$$\lceil\log_y(t)\rceil=n\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n-1<\log_y(t)\leq n \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad y^{n-1}< t\leq y^n\ ;$$
furthermore the third statement implies $n\geq1$. Therefore we have to prove the following:

When $y\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq2}$ and $x>1$ then
$$y^{n-1}< \lceil x\rceil\leq y^n\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad y^{n-1}<x\leq y^n\ .\tag{1}$$
*Proof* of $\Rightarrow:\ $ Since $n\geq1$ the number $y^{n-1}$ is an integer. It follows that $\lceil x\rceil\geq y^{n-1}+1$ and therefore $x>\lceil x\rceil-1\geq y^{n-1}$. On the other hand $x\leq\lceil x\rceil\leq y^n$.

The converse is similar.

Summing it all up we can say that the statement is **true** when $y\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq2}$ and $x>{1\over y}$.

Comment: This is very similar to what I have tried at first. I was stuck at proving either direction. Anyway, great answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It might be instructive to determine, for a given base $y > 1$, those values $x > 0$ such that $f_y(x) = \lceil \log_y \lceil x \rceil \rceil \ne g_y(x) = \lceil \log_y x \rceil$.  First, it is easy to see from the fact that $\log$ is monotone increasing that $f_y(x) \ge g_y(x)$ for any base $y > 1$.  Furthermore, we note that if $f_y(x) = g_y(x) = n$, then both $\log_y \lceil x \rceil$ and $\log_y x$ must lie in the same interval $(n-1, n]$; that is to say, both $\lceil x \rceil$ and $x$ must lie in the interval $(y^{n-1}, y^n]$.  Is this always true?  Of course not:  if $y$ is not an integer, then it is easy to see that $x \in (\lfloor y^n \rfloor, y^n]$ implies $\lceil x \rceil > y^n$.

But what if $y$ *is* an integer?  Then we almost get away, but remember there is the interval $x \in (0,1)$.  In such a case, $\lceil x \rceil = 1$ and $f_y(x) = 0$, but $g_y(x)$ is not zero unless $x > y^{-1}$.  So we always have a counterexample to the asserted identity for $x \in (0, 1/y]$, regardless of whether $y$ is an integer.